# LEGO 3069 tile 1x2 (dark?)grey with red and gold pattern and with yellow and white pattern

Tags: part-identification

Does anyone know the exact names of the tiles or which set they belong to?

### Gold and Red

[image]

### Yellow and White

[image]

Comment: Wow this is old LEGO. I had this pieces something like 20 yeas ago.

Comment: The bottom one is used in several sets as recent as 2020. It's been around for about 20 years.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first tile is [Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Copper and White Circuitry, Red Rectangle and 4 Squares Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bpa2)
[image]
Appearing in [these 10](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bpa2&in=S) sets.
It looks like yours is Dark Gray.

The second tile is [Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with Vehicle Control Panel Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bpc1)
[image]
Appearing in [these 82](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3069bpc1&in=S) sets.
It looks like yours is Dark Bluish Gray.